# How can I find where is the docker container directory in host machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can find the docker container id by docker ps

I also knew that the containers are stored under /var/lib/docker/containers/

But the  returned by `docker ps` doesn't match any of the directories' id.

So how can I find which directory stores which containers files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below command to get the JSON output of all the mounts used by the container (container-Id). *The value of "Source" key in the output json will be the host directory* :

```
docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' <container-Id>
```

Prettify json by piping the output to **jq** or **python** json module:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' <container-Id> | python -m json.tool
docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' <container-Id> | jq
```